# How do you compare 3 arguments or more in racket?

Tags: racket, comparison-operators

I know that in Racket to compare for example two numbers you will have something like this.

```
  (define (myMax x y)
           (if (< x y) y x))
```

My question is how do you compare for a function with 3 arguments or more. For example to get the highest number from the arguments.

```
(define (myMax x y z)
```

Comment: You can use the max built-in procedure for this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to process an undefined number of elements, you need to work with `list`.

The idiomatic way is to use `recursion` to process the elements. Each function call need to process one element (`car`) and the rest of the list `cdr`.

You can find an implementation on a another post:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/42463097/10953006

EDIT 1: EXAMPLE

```
(define (maximum L)
     (if (null? (cdr L)) 
         (car L) 
         (if (< (car L) (maximum (cdr L)))  
             (maximum (cdr L)) 
             (car L))))

(maximum '( 1 2 3 ))
(maximum '( 1 2 3 4))
(maximum '( 1 2 3 4 5))
```

Give the results:

```
3
4
5
```

EDIT 2: if the real question is about `variable number of arguments` in Racket, you could use the following notation:

```
(define (test-function . L)
  (printf "~S~%" L)) ;; Here: L is the list (1 2 3)

(test-function 1 2 3)
```

Which will display (`printf`):

```
(1 2 3)
```

Comment: I don't know the reason of being downvoted. Prior to publish this answer I tested the code in Racket IDE and it provide an implementation of `myMax` which work with a list.